# FragmentManager add multiple instances of the same Fragment type

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have the need to "stack up" fragments one on top of another. I do this by:

```
    String className = fragment.getClass().getName();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, className);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(className);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Within:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

This all works good as long as the fragments are of different type.

However if I create a second instance of a fragment type that is already there then there is an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: TestFragment{1184e8a1 #0 id=0x7f0800ef com.test.ui.TestFragment}
```

How can I add multiple instances of the same fragment?

One requirement is that they are all on top of each other - because few of them have a small margin that lets you see small portion of the fragment underneath.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) Use different tags for each added fragment. 2) Make sure you add them to a `FrameLayout` (which will stack them on top of each other) not `LinearLayout` (which will put them beside each other).

Answer (score 1):

Layout of parent fragment

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_contentrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

code in parent fragment to add child fragment

```
 FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

    for (int x = 1; x < 5; x = x + 1) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_contentrow, new MyChildFragment(), "Tag " + x);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Wont work since this breaks the requirement at the bottom ("... top of each other ...")

Comment: Are you adding the fragments in another fragment since you are using getChildFragmentManager(); in code ?

Comment: Yes they are added within one main fragment that is initialized and shown at startup, but that shouldn't make a different right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new instance of your fragment instead of replacing it with the same object over and over again.

```
fragment = new YourFragment();
fragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =     fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, className)
    .addToBackStack(className);
    .commit();
```

Also I suggest to change tags between fragments, for example you can add a number to it.

Comment: Yes it is a new instance of the Fragment every single time

Comment: Did you change tags too?